# TLS bootstrapping ,--token-auth-file, User "system:anonymous" cannot create certificatesigningrequests

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

why i set --token-auth-file on api-server and set --bootstrap-kubeconfig on the worker node, i was specified the username is "kubelet-bootstrap" on apiserver and the worker node, and i got the error says User "system:anonymous" ?

> error: failed to run Kubelet: cannot create certificate signing
>   request:  certificatesigningrequests.certificates.k8s.io is forbidden:
>   User  "system:anonymous" cannot create
>   certificatesigningrequests.certificates.k8s.io  at the cluster scope

kubernetes version v1.8.3

below is my configuration

apiserver:

```
/usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379
  --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota
  --service-account-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/pubkey.pem
  --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/16
  --allow-privileged=true
  --authorization-mode=RBAC
  --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
  --token-auth-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/bootstrap.csv
  --client-ca-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/cacert.pem
  --tls-cert-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/servercert.pem
  --tls-private-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/serverkey.pem
  --address=172.18.11.249
  --insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1
  --advertise-address=172.18.11.249
  --audit-log-maxage=30
  --audit-log-maxsize=100
  --audit-log-path=/var/log/kube-apiserver.log
  --v=4
  1>>/var/log/kube-apiserver.log 2>&1
```

/var/lib/kubernetes/bootstrap.csv

```
0d681e2438667d2b5236ad7385d80ddc,kubelet-bootstrap,10001,"system:kubelet-bootstrap"
```

worker node:

```
/usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubelet/bootstrap.kubeconfig.yaml 
                 --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests 
                 --node-labels=node-role.kubernetes.io/worker= 
                 --node-ip=172.18.10.16 
                 --allow-privileged 
                 --v=4
```

/etc/kubelet/bootstrap.kubeconfig.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
  - cluster:
      server: https://172.18.11.249:6443/
    name: myk8s
contexts:
  - context:
      cluster: myk8s
    name: myk8s
current-context: myk8s
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubelet-bootstrap
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    token: 0d681e2438667d2b5236ad7385d80ddc
```

log from worker node

> I0821 08:49:50.916993    6232 bootstrap.go:57] Using bootstrap
>   kubeconfig to generate TLS client cert, key and kubeconfig file
>
> error: failed to run Kubelet: cannot create certificate signing
>   request: certificatesigningrequests.certificates.k8s.io is forbidden:
>   User "system:anonymous" cannot create
>   certificatesigningrequests.certificates.k8s.io at the cluster scope

log from apiserver

> I0821 08:05:05.726968       5 rbac.go:116] RBAC DENY: user
>   "system:anonymous" groups ["system:unauthenticated"] cannot "create"
>   resource "certificatesigningrequests.certificates.k8s.io" cluster-wide
>   I0821 08:05:05.727015       5 authorization.go:59] Forbidden:
>   "/apis/certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1/certificatesigningrequests",
>   Reason: ""

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token format in your `bootstrap.kubeconfig.yaml` looks different than usual tokens that are generated by `kubeadm`.

According to the article [Authenticating with Bootstrap Tokens](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/bootstrap-tokens/):

> ### Token Format
>
> Bootstrap Tokens take the form of abcdef.0123456789abcdef. More
>   formally, they must match the regular expression
>   [a-z0-9]{6}.[a-z0-9]{16}.
>
> The first part of the token is the “Token ID” and is considered public
>   information. It is used when referring to a token without leaking the
>   secret part used for authentication. The second part is the “Token
>   Secret” and should only be shared with trusted parties.

Consider reading the [previous](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/bootstrap-tokens/) and [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/cluster-lifecycle/bootstrap-discovery.md#method-bootstrap-token) article to understand how the Bootstrap Token idea is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you don't have the clusterrolebindings for `system:anonymous`, as by default it is disabled to protect the cluster from DoS attacks.

There is a configMap in a kube-public namespace that should be used for TLS bootstrapping. If a node wants to join the cluster automatically, it needs some information. This is when comes in this configMap. But the node has to have the permissions to read the file.